# React Native Navigation - [FAB]floating action button does not display as expected

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am working with a React-native-navigation(wix) and there is a problem associated with React native FAB (Floating action button).

Requirement - I need to set FAB inside the componentDidMount lifecycle method as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigator.setButtons({
    fab: {
     collapsedId: "someFormName",
     ...getAddButtonStyle()
    }
  });
}
```

I manage `this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));` globally and it work as expected. The problem here I have is the FAB is not showing as expected in my UI when I set it inside the `componentDidMount()` but if I set as a  `static button` it works perfectly. Also it does the job perfectly inside `render()` function.

I am confused why can't I set the button inside `componentDidMount()` [initial page load] ?